# Is it possible to find the present index in an enhanced for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

Is it possible to find the present index in an enhanced for loop? If so how?

I am aware we can check it with an extra variable. But is there any other way.

```
public boolean cancelTicket(Flight f, Customer c) {
    List<BookingDetails> l = c.getBooking();
    if (l.size() < 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (BookingDetails bd : l) {
            if(bd.getFlight()==f){
                l.remove()  // Index here..
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: `if (list.size() < 0)`. Maybe you meant `==` instead?

Comment: Check this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java

Comment: Even if you did have the index, attempting to remove the element from the list in an enhanced for loop would cause a ConcurrentModificationException. Use an iterator as suggested by @aioobe

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> ***Is it possible to find the present index in an enhanced for loop?***

No. If you need the index, I suggest you use an ordinary for-loop.

However, you don't actually seem to need the index in this situation. Unless you're dealing with some really strange type of list, you could go with an `Iterator` and use the `Iterator.remove()` method, like this:

```
public boolean cancelTicket(Flight f, Customer c) {
    Iterator<BookingDetails> bdIter = c.getBooking().iterator();

    if (!bdIter.hasNext())
        return false;

    while (bdIter.hasNext())
        if (bdIter.next().getFlight() == f)
            bdIter.remove();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: "You don't need the index for the remove operation in this particular situation though" - moreover, you *can't* use the index for the remove operation, because if you do, you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. As aioobe says, the correct way to do this is with `Iterator.remove()`.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, Use a counter before the for statement.
as such:

```
int i = 0;
for (int s : ss)
{
   // Some Code
   System.out.println(i);

   i++;
}
```

Comment: Best and most efficient answer ;-)

Comment: Although this is the most straightforward way to go, one must take extra caution when using the continue statement with this. Basically, wherever you use the continue keyword in the body of the for loop, it must be preceded by an i++ instruction, otherwise funny things can happen. To avoid having to worry about this, use a standard for loop, and in the first line do something like Item item = list.get(i). This way you get both the index and the object.

Answer (score 10):

> ***Is it possible to find the present index in an enhanced for loop?***

For getting the index, you can use `List.indexOf(object)`.

I have used these techniques for getting index of current object in a list.
For example you given above, the removal can be done using two ways.

- Using object instance to remove object.

> ```
>  public boolean cancelTicket(Flight f, Customer c) {
>         List<BookingDetails> l = c.getBooking();
>         if (l.size() < 0) {
>             return false;
>         } else {
>             for (BookingDetails bd : l) {
>                 if(bd.getFlight()==f){
>                     l.remove(bd)  // Object Instance here..
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

- Using List.indexOf(index)

> ```
>  public boolean cancelTicket(Flight f, Customer c) {
>         List<BookingDetails> l = c.getBooking();
>         if (l.size() < 0) {
>             return false;
>         } else {
>             for (BookingDetails bd : l) {
>                 if(bd.getFlight()==f){
>                     l.remove(l.indexOf(bd))  // index Number here..
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: List.indexOf is O(n) so I try to avoid using it in general.

Comment: Also, indexOf always returns the first occurance of the object in the list, which may not be what you want.

Comment: READER BEWARE! This is definitely not the way to go! Not only is this very slow (O(n^2)), but possibly incorrect (e.g., for duplicate values in list).