# Removing object from ArrayList in for each loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to remove an object from an `ArrayList` when I'm done with it, but I can't find way to do it. Trying to remove it like in the sample code below doesn't want to work. How could I get to the iterator of current `px` object in this loop to remove it?

```
for( Pixel px : pixel){ 
[...]
  if(px.y > gHeigh){
     pixel.remove(pixel.indexOf(px)); // here is the thing
     pixel.remove(px); //doesn't work either
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can't, within the enhanced for loop. You have to use the "long-hand" approach:

```
for (Iterator<Pixel> iterator = pixels.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
  Pixel px = iterator.next();
  if(px.y > gHeigh){
    iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

Of course, not all iterators *support* removal, but you should be fine with `ArrayList`.

An alternative is to build an additional collection of "pixels to remove" then call `removeAll` on the list at the end.

Answer (score 24):

Using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) and [lamdba expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), the method [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) has been introduced for collections.

> Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given
>   predicate.

So it will only take one line :

```
pixels.removeIf(px -> px.y > gHeigh);
```

Comment: by the way `removeIf` uses `Iterator` and `while` loop. You can see it at java 8 `java.util.Collection.java`

Comment: @omerhakanbilici This is only the default implementation. You can see it has been optimized for `ArrayList`s for instance.

Answer (score 2):

you need to create and access the iterator explicitly

```
Iterator<Pixel> it = pixel.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
Pixel.px = it.next();
//...
it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify a Collection while someone is iterating over it, even if that someone were you. Use normal for cycle:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pixel.size(); i++){
    if(pixel.get(i).y > gHeigh){
        pixel.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have the issue of the next loop needing to be on index `i` again and you need to ensure it is not incremented

Answer (score 1):

use a regular `for` loop, the enhanced `for` loop maintains an iterator, and doesn't allow for removal of objects, or use the iterator explicitly

Edit: see answer of the this question [Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If Pixel is your own custom object then you need to implement the equals and hashcode method for your Pixel object. The indexOf method also finds the index using equals method. Try implementing that and check it out.