# ConcurrentModification Exception in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, iterator, synchronized

I know there are many questions asked on this but in my case i have it in a synchronised block and i am sure that nobody will be changing my array list.. But still i get this exception SOMETIMES if i am using for-each loop.. Why ?

Here is my code snippet

```
    final static Object mLock = new Object();
private static ArrayList<ConnectionAndAuthCallback> mCallbacks;
private void callAuthCallbacks() {
        synchronized (mLock) {

            if (mCallbacks != null)
                for (ConnectionAndAuthCallback calback : mCallbacks) { //here i get exception
                    calback.onAuthentication(mToken, calback.intent);
                }
        }
    }
```

here is the code i do on Callback

```
@Override
            public void onAuthentication(String token, Intent intent) {
                web.loadUrl("xyz.com");
                //unregister so that we wong get any exception or some more callbacks
                SameClass.unRegisterAuthCallbacks(this); 
            }
```

and in Unregister function

```
public static void unRegisterAuthCallbacks(ConnectionAndAuthCallback callback) {
        synchronized (mLock) {

            if (mCallbacks != null)
                if (mCallbacks.contains(callback)) {
                    mCallbacks.remove(callback); // This causing problem ?? In same thread "syncronised" wont work ??
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems you are on wrong track. This code block should not cause this exception.

Comment: Where else in your code do you use `mCallbacks`? Are you iterating through `mCallbacks` at some point prior to the call to `callAuthCallbacks()`?

Comment: You could always create your own `ArrayList` subclass that logs whenever the list is changed and by whom, and substitute that in. That's always a fun debugging technique.

Comment: Yes, mCallbacks gets iterated through in some other places too but they are too inside `sync` block

Comment: Well, that's strange. Doesn't seem like the exception should be happening, and if none of us can reproduce your problem, helping you will be somewhat difficult... Try the `ArrayList` subclass thing and see if that helps?

Comment: Does that `onAuthentication` method modify the list in any way?

Comment: @chrylis Probably, `OnAuthentication` is a callback, in app on that callback i call unregister callback and in that i remove `this` object from list, But even remove code inside `synchronised` block with same static lock.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. Your `for` loop is holding an open iterator on the list; even if other code is operating under the same lock, if it modifies the list, you'll get the exception.

Comment: Aaaaand there we go. Your `ArrayList` indeed was being changed. `synchronized` of course won't work in the same thread. How do you synchronize one thread?

Comment: Yep, there's your problem.

Comment: @user3580294 actually it gets called from many other thread also.. This is onee of the case i used so i used synchronised.. Thanks BTW.

Comment: I see... Just be careful in the future. `synchronized` only protects against *external* threads. It won't prevent you from doing whatever you want inside a particular thread.

Comment: BUT why do i get this "sometimes" only ?

Comment: Maybe because `mCallbacks` only sometimes contains `callback`? Or maybe because the callback to remove was at the end of `mCallbacks` for some portion of the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was, In the same thread `synchronised(){}` wont work. 
Even if you think it works then there might be a dead lock.

In my case i was removing callback object from `ArrayList` in the same thread where i called callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform modifications on an ArrayList or remove() in this case that you are currently reading out of or looping through. Use iterators instead.

[Check out this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java)
[And this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691328/removing-object-from-arraylist-in-for-each-loop)

Comment: I had gone through this before i asked this question. And obiously it solves the problem.