# Comparing data numbers, Iterator.remove() throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator

I am trying to make an Android app that can compare integers. However, when I am trying to compare integers and I need to delete some entries because they are redundant or they do not fit in, I cannot use Iterator.remove() without encountering a NullPointerException. Here is the specific output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          Process: com.daita.musicale, PID: 22649
          java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
              at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
              at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
              at com.daita.musicale.MainActivity.checkNotes(MainActivity.java:115)
              at com.daita.musicale.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the code region(at com.daita.musicale.MainActivity.checkNotes(MainActivity.java:115)) that is giving me the error.

```
public boolean[] checkNumbers(String code1, String code2) {
    if (code != null) {
        List<String> c1 = Arrays.asList(code1.replace("-1.0,", "").replace("null", "").split(","));
        List<String> c2 = Arrays.asList(code2.replace("-1.0,", "").replace("null", "").split(","));
        Iterator<String> c1iterator = c1.iterator();
        Iterator<String> c2iterator = c2.iterator();
        boolean strike = false;
        double prev = 0;
        int i = 0;
        boolean[] correctness = new boolean[c1.size()];
        while (c1iterator.hasNext()) {
            double c1hertz = Double.parseDouble(c1iterator.next());
            double c2hertz = Double.parseDouble(c2iterator.next());
            double difference = c1hertz - c2hertz;
            if (difference > -1 && difference < 1) {
                correctness[i] = true;
                double prevDifference = prev - c1hertz;
                if (prevDifference > -1 && prevDifference < 1) {
                    c1iterator.remove(); //specific issue location! (this is line 115 of MainActivity)
                    c2iterator.remove();
                    i = 0;
                    correctness = new boolean[c1.size()];
                } else {
                    prev = c1hertz;
                    correctness[i] = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (strike) {
                    correctness[i] = false;
                    try {
                        correctness[i - 1] = false;
                    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe) {
                        aioobe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    correctness[i] = true;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return correctness;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have looked at other questions on both Code Review and Stack Overflow, for example:

[Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java)
[Removing object from ArrayList in for each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691328/removing-object-from-arraylist-in-for-each-loop)
Removing elements on a List while iterating through it
I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) version is *immutable*, that's the *exact* reason why it's throwing an  `UnsupportedOperationException`.

as stated by java docs:

> [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) returns a ***fixed-size*** list backed by the specified array.

that simply means you *cannot* modify the list.

Solution:

```
List<String> c1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(code1.replace("-1.0,", "")
.replace("null", "").split(",")));

List<String> c2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(code2.replace("-1.0,", "")
.replace("null", "").split(",")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList because it supports removal with iterating

```
List<String> c1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(code1.replace("-1.0,", "").replace("null", "").split(",")));
List<String> c2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(code2.replace("-1.0,", "").replace("null", "").split(",")));
```

Comment: This is an equally good answer, @berrytchaks, just that I saw and used the other one first.

Comment: Glad that you got unstuck even though it is was not because of my solution ;)