# Remove from a collection during iteration

Tags: java

I have set of `connection` objects (library code I cannot change) that have a `send` method.  If the sending fails, they call back a generic `onClosed` listener which I implement that calls `removeConnection()` in my code, which will remove the connection from the collection.

The `onClosed` callback is generic and can be called at any time.  It is called when the peer closes the connection, for example, and not just when a write fails.

***However***, if I have some code that loops over my connections and sends, then the `onClosed` callback will attempt to modify a collection during iteration.

My current code creates a *copy* of the connections list before each iteration over it; however, in profiling this has shown to be very expensive.

```
Set<Connection> connections = new ....;

public void addConnection(Connection conn) {
    connections.add(conn);
    conn.addClosedListener(this);
}

@Override void onClosed(Connection conn) {
    connections.remove(conn);
}

void send(Message msg) {
    // how to make this so that the onClosed callback can be safely invoked, and efficient?
    for(Connection conn: connections)
        conn.send(msg);
}
```

How can I efficiently cope with modifying collections during iteration?

Comment: `An Iterator is an object that enables you to traverse through a collection and to remove elements from the collection selectively, if desired` may be I don't understand clearly your situation but I think that you can remove elements from collection during iteration and you don't get any exception

Comment: on what @aleksei bulgak said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) is probably what you want.

You could also use a [CopyOnWriteArraySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html). This of course will still make a copy, however, it will only do so when the set is modified. So as long as `Connection` objects are not added or removed regularly, this would be more efficient.

Comment: I discovered that the skip list needs objects to be comparable ... which is a runtime exception, not a compiler error.  Nasty.  But CopyOnWriteArraySet was much easier to retrofit, and seems to be working.  Am benchmarking now.  Thx!

Answer (score 3):

To iterate a collection with the concurrent modification without any exceptions use `List Iterator`.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-loop-iterate-a-list-in-java/ - example

If you use simple `for` or `foreach` loops, you will receive `ConcurrentModificationException` during the element removing - be careful on that.

As an addition, you could override the `List Iterator` with your own one and add the needed logic. Just implement the `java.util.Iterator` interface.

Comment: but the removal has to happen through the iterator, and the callback does not know this....

Comment: If you do not have access to the iterator, then you have to stay with your copied collection.

Comment: +1 and article on this theme : How to Avoid ConcurrentModificationException when using an Iterator  http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html

Comment: -1 This was never a solution based on the OP's stated problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a collection wrapper that:

1. Keeps a set of objects that are to be removed. If the iteration across the underlying collection comes across one of these it is skipped.
2. On completion of iteration, takes a second pass across the list to remove all of the gathered objects.

Perhaps something like this:

```
class ModifiableIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
  // My iterable.
  final Iterable<T> it;
  // The Iterator we are walking.
  final Iterator<T> i;
  // The removed objects.
  Set<T> removed = new HashSet<T>();
  // The next actual one to return.
  T next = null;

  public ModifiableIterator(Iterable<T> it) {
    this.it = it;
    i = it.iterator();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    while ( next == null && i.hasNext() ) {
      // Pull a new one.
      next = i.next();
      if ( removed.contains(next)) {
        // Not that one.
        next = null;
      }
    }
    if ( next == null ) {
      // Finished! Close.
      close();
    }
    return next != null;
  }

  @Override
  public T next() {
    T n = next;
    next = null;
    return n;
  }

  // Close down - remove all removed.
  public void close () {
    if ( !removed.isEmpty() ) {
      Iterator<T> i = it.iterator();

      while ( i.hasNext() ) {
        if ( removed.contains(i.next())) {
          i.remove();
        }
      }
      // Clear down.
      removed.clear();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
  }

  public void remove(T t) {
    removed.add(t);
  }

}

public void test() {
  List<String> test = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D","E"));
  ModifiableIterator i = new ModifiableIterator(test);
  i.remove("A");
  i.remove("E");
  System.out.println(test);
  while ( i.hasNext() ) {
    System.out.println(i.next());
  }
  System.out.println(test);
}
```

You may need to consider whether your list could contain null values, in which case you will need to tweak it somewhat.

Please remember to `close` the iterator if you abandon the iteration before it completes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ConcurrentHashMap. 
ConcurrentHashMap is thread-safe, so you don't need to make a copy in order to be able to iterate. 
Take a look at this implementation..   http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/Concurrentset.htm