# ConcurrentModificationException error

Tags: exception

could somebody help me to solve my code problem? Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:894)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:928)
    at javaTest.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Code is:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    job.add("a");
    job.add("b");
    HashSet<String> klonasOnJob = job;
    for (String p : klonasOnJob) {
        if (p != "b") {

        } else {
            job.remove(p);
        }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java/1196611#1196611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most collections will break and throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if you modify the collection (in your case by removing an element) while iterating over the collection. Use the iterator's `remove()` method instead.

In your case the relevant fragment would be:

```
Iterator<String> it = klonasOnJob.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String p = it.next();
    if (p != "b") {

    } else {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I'm not modifying the collection while iterating, I create another HashMap and copied it's content to the another. 

HashSet<String> klonasOnJob = job;
job.remove(p);

Comment: You only set the reference `klonasOnJob` to point to the same object as `job` - this is what assignment does in Java: it just copies the reference and doesn't create a copy of the object like in C++.

Comment: So basically by removing with this line job.remove(p); 

I remove from job and klonasOnJob, am I right?

Comment: Yes - it's just two names that both refer to the same object.