# Remove min and max values from an iterable collection

Tags: java, iterator

I have a method that looks like

```
public double calculator(Iterable<Integer> userRating)
```

I'm trying to implement logic that removes the highest and lowest values and calculate the average. The end result should look like (removing the mins -2, and maxs 15)

```
public void ProperlyCalculates() {
        List<Integer> ratings = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ratings.add(-2);
        ratings.add(-2);
        ratings.add( 3);
        ratings.add( 7);
        ratings.add( 8);
        ratings.add( 9);
        ratings.add(15);
        ratings.add(15);
        ratings.add(15);
        double rating = rater.getMovieRating(ratings);
        assertEquals(6.75D, rating, 0.0000001D);
```

I'm confusing myself trying to create an iterator that I can loop through and add in my logic. So far I have tried.

```
public double getMovieRating(Iterable<Integer> userRating) {


        Iterator ratings = userRating.iterator();
        int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        while (ratings.hasNext()) {
            Integer val = ratings.next();
            if (val > max){ max = val;}
            if (val < min) {min = val;}  

        }

    }
```

But `Integer val = ratings.next()` throws an `incompatible type` error. How can I can loop through all of the values in the iterator? Is this a case where I would need a private inner class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can fix this problem. Either provide a type for the `Iterator`, like this

```
Iterator<Integer> ratings = userRating.iterator(); // An iterator of type Integer
```

or cast the value returned from the `iterator.next()` to an `Integer`, like this

```
Integer val = (Integer) ratings.next();
```

In the first case, you ensure that every element returned by the `Iterator` will be of the type `Integer` only. And in the second case, you cast the value to an `Integer` because an `Iterator` without a type would return an `Object` by default.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @R.J said, you should also consider using for:next syntax, as it makes this much simpler:

```
public double getMovieRating(Iterable<Integer> userRating) {

    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for(Integer rating : userRating) {
        final int val = rating.intValue();
        if (val > max){ max = val;}
        if (val < min) {min = val;}  
    }
}
```

Comment: hrmm, that gives an error `cannot resolve symbol rating`. what's missing?

Comment: I was missing the type for rating. I have updated the example.