# How to search an arraylist of accounts for an account with the account number specified as a parameter

Tags: java, arraylist

My code compiles but it returns -1 regardless of what I input, correct or not

```
public int search(String accountNumber){
       int index = 0;
       boolean found = false;

       for (Account account : accounts )
            while(index < accounts.size() && !found)
                if (accounts.get(index).equals (accountNumber)) 
                    found = true;  

                else 
                    index++;

        if (found == true)
            return index;
        else
            return -1;

    }
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to return the account number from that index position but I'm really struggling to solve this

Edit: Also I'm not sure how to correct this in order to make it work

/**
      Should remove the Account with the account number specified 
      as a parameter if it the Account exists. 
      The appropriate boolean value should then be returned via a 
     method result dialog box.
     */

```
public boolean removeAccount(String accountNumber)
{
    int index = 0;
    for(Account account : accounts)
    {
        if((account.getAccountNumber() == accountNumber) && index < accounts.size())
            accounts.remove(account);
        else
            index++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply `return index` instead of setting `found = true`? And by the way, those two loops one inside the other are completely redundant. You only need **one** loop!!! For the sake of returning an index, the `while` loop would make an easier choice.

Comment: @dana the problem is in your if statement under while loop.

Comment: The simplest answer is do not use a for each loop use a normal for loop. If you find it then just return i; after the for loop just put return -1;

Comment: Something is fundamentally wrong here. `accounts.get(...)` returns an `Account` object, while `accountNumber` is of type `String`. Would you mind explaining what exactly are you trying to compare???

Comment: @Dana it's not a good idea to remove item inside for each loop. For this purpose you should use iterator. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java]

Answer (score 1):

did you override the `equals` method in Account class. otherwise it will not work.
because you compare Accounts with String.
also `if (found)` is enough rather than `if (found == true)`

Answer (score 1):

**You have two major problems:**

1. You are using a loop inside a loop, which is completely redundant for your purpose here
2. You are comparing an `Account` object to a `String` object, which is probably not what you want

**Here are the possible solutions:**

Option #1:

```
for (Account account : accounts)
    if (account.getNumber().equals(accountNumber))
        return accounts.indexOf(account);
return -1;
```

Option #2:

```
int size = accounts.size();
for (int index=0; index<size; index++)
    if (accounts.get(index).getNumber().equals(accountNumber))
        return index;
return -1;
```

Of course, you will need to implement method `public String getNumber()` in class `Account`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int search(String accountNumber){
   int index = 0;

   for (Account account : accounts ){
       if(account.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber))
          return index;
        else
           index++;
    }
   return -1;
}
```

Try this right now i dont have java setup but this should work.
NOTE: Write a getter in your Account class which return account number.

************************************Solution for you second problem*****************************

```
public boolean removeAccount(String accountNumber)
{
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if(account.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber))
          return accounts.remove(account);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: not sure how to implement the iterator? Haven't done it yet in classes

Comment: @Dana please see the second part of solution for **remove**

Comment: i'm getting incompatible types - void canot be converted to boolean

Answer (score 0):

You need a getNum() method in your Account class. Unless Account extends String.
This should work properly and simplify things.

```
public int search(String accountNumber){
for(int i=0;i<accounts.size();i++){
 if(accounts.get(i).getNum().equals(accountNumber))
  return i;
}
return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code:

```
public int search(String accountNumber){
   int index = 0;

   while(index < accounts.size()-1 && !Arrays.asList(accounts).contains(accountNumber)))
   {
       index++;
   }

    if  (accounts.get(index).equals (accountNumber))
        return index;
    else
        return -1;
    }
}
```

You don't need to iterate over all the arraylist, if you find it you return its index.

Well then try the Edit of the while condition.

Comment: This code will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the searched account cannot be found.

Comment: Yes it's the problem of `accounts.size()` .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. I haven't written any new code, but just refined yours.

```
public int search(String accountNumber){
   int index = 0;
   boolean found = false;

   for (Account account : accounts )
   {
        if(index < accounts.size() && !found)
            if (accounts.get(index).equals (accountNumber)) 
                {
                 found = true;
                 break;
                }


            else 
                index++;

 }   
 if (found == true)
        return index;
    else
        return -1;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work try this..

```
public int search(String accountNumber)
{
 int index = -1;

 for(int i=0;i<accounts.size();i++)
 {
   if(accounts.get(i).getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber))
    {
    index=i;
    break;
    }
 }
 return index;   
}
```

I have initialized index with -1 you may use 0 also and setter getter should be there in Account for accountNumber variable to write as accounts.get(i).getAccountNumber()