# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException & iteration?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, iterator, concurrentmodification

I'm so very new to Arraylists & iterators & this is the first time I got this exception.
I have an ArrayList u & I'd like to do the following algorithm:

```
for (Character c:u){

    if(k==1){           //base case

        if(isAnswer(s+u.get(0)))

            System.out.println(s+u.get(0)+" is the correct sequence."+ '\n');
        return;
    }

    else{
        u.remove(c);
        puzzleSolve(k-1, s+c , u);
        u.add(c);
        removeLastChar(s);
    }

    } //end of for each
```

as I searched this exception a little bit i found out I can't remove iterms weth for each on a arraylist & I need to use iterator
but i kinna got confused where & how exactly i must put the while(iter.hasNext()) & such stuff for this piece of code.
i would be more than grateful if you could help me

PS. s is String ( initially empty) & k is int

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java

Answer (score 1):

> *how exactly i must put the while(iter.hasNext())*

You can use `iterator` as below:

```
Iterator<Character> iter = u.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
  Character c = iter.next();
  .....
}
```

Initialize your list with generics: `List<Character> u = new ArrayList<Character>();`

**Hint**: use `iter.remove()`, `iter.add()` wherever applicable instead of `u.remove()` and `u.add()`.

You need to start here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm

Comment: & then my entire if else in between?!

Comment: Yes. Your code between it. It acts as a `replacement` for the `enhanced for loop`, in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Iterator<Character> iter = u.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
{
    Character currentChar = iter.next();

    if(k==1){           //base case

        if(isAnswer(s+u.get(0)))

        System.out.println(s+u.get(0)+" is the correct sequence."+ '\n');
        return;
    }

    else{
         iter.remove();
         puzzleSolve(k-1, s+currentChar  , u);
         u.add(currentChar);
         removeLastChar(s);
    }
```

}

Comment: thanks, i did yet it still throws the same exception at lines:

Comment: Character currentChar = iter.next();

Comment: and another line i have called the sovePuzzle method

Comment: It works fine for me...can you update your post with the exact stack trace you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **foreach** loop, you are using **iterator implicitly**.

**ConcurrentModificationException** occurs when the collection is modified by "simultaneously" with the passage of an iterator over a collection by any means, except for the iterator.

So, use **iterator**

```
Iterator<Character> iter = u.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
```

in cases you need to modify collection in loop.