# Java: for loops and Iterators

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator

Every For Loop with an Iterator that i've ever used (to use the *Iterator.remove();* method) looks like this:

```
for (Iterator<E> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    E element = iter.next();
    //some code
}
```

Basic For Loops are styled:

```
for([initial statement]; [loop condition]; [iterating statement]) {/*Some Code*/}
```

So my question is... why are they never written

```
for (Iterator<E> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); E element = iter.next()) {
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iterating statement executes *after* the loop body has executed. In other words, when you write the following:

```
for (Iterator<E> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); element = iter.next()) {
   //some code
}
```

`element = iter.next()` would run after the body has run for each iteration, so if you are printing the element, for example, the first element would be whatever initial value `element` had.

**Example:**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a1");
list.add("a2");
list.add("a3");
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String string =  iterator.next();
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

**Output:**

```
a1
a2
a3
```

With the `iter.next()` in the `for` loop:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a1");
list.add("a2");
list.add("a3");
String string = null;
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); string = iterator.next()) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

**Output:**

```
null
a1
a2
```

**P.S.:** The loop as you declared (`for (Iterator<E> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); E element = iter.next())` will not compile, so you would need to declare `element` as a variable before this line.

Answer (score 6):

The `for` loop grammar does not permit you to declare a variable in the "iterating statement".

(You can declare one in the "initial statement" which is why `for (Iterator<E> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )` is syntatically valid.)

Answer (score -1):

Given that a `for` loop is just syntactic sugar around a `while` loop, and you cannot use the "iterating statement" the way you want, it might be neater to use a `while` loop directly:

```
Iterator<E> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  E element = iter.next();
  //some code
}
```

Comment: It's best practice to minimize the scope of local variables.

Comment: It's better than before but still not minimized. The minimal scope in this case is the scope of the loop, if you don't need the variable outside of the loop.

Comment: @Puce I think readability is more important than "best practice" rules on scoping. Look at this question, I'd say this method is the most commonly used. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1196612/360211

Comment: I agree that readability is more important, but I find this version less readable since my eyes have to check more scopes. If I see such a variable outside the loop scope I start to wonder if it is used outside that scope and for what reason. If in the end it isn't used at all outside the loop scope then it's a check I wouldn't have needed to do if the scope of the variable has been minimized. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @Puce Looked a bit further, I think both ways are pretty common http://stackoverflow.com/a/223929/360211

Comment: I know that it is quite common, but that doesn't make it better. I see it every now and then at code reviews.

Comment: @Puce Maybe your methods are too long. Mine are 4-5 lines max.  Any more lines and it's doing too much and can refactored into smaller methods. This example, would definitely be in it's own method. So no question about what `iter` is used for outside the loop. It will always be in a pretty short scope in good SRP code.