# 'instanceof' being inconsistent

Tags: java, javafx

Hey programming student here.

I have a JavaFX application. I have a pane, and I want to remove all rectangles from it. Here is the code:

```
public Pane yard = new Pane();
...
for(int i = 0; i < yard.getChildren().size(); i++)
{
    if(yard.getChildren().get(i) instanceof Rectangle)
    {
        yard.getChildren().remove(i);
    }
 }
```

This works fine, sometimes.  Other times it simply fails to remove anything.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: `This works fine, sometimes. Other times it simply fails to remove anything` with this statement it is hard to tell exact problem. Debug step by step and try to understand why it fails.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `instanceof`. [This Q&A provides a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/223918/335858).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are calling remove within your for loop. You can't do that. If your for loop starts with 10 entries, the item at position 6 might be a rectangle to start with. However if you remove the 5th entry in your list, what was at position 6 will be at position 5 and be skipped over.

Example:

```
yard.getChildren[0] = square
yard.getChildren[1] = square
yard.getChildren[2] = rectangle
yard.getChildren[3] = rectangle.
```

you can see the item at index 2 will be removed, meaning that the size of yard.getChildren is now 3. Your counter i will also be 3 at this point. Therefore the for loop will stop, and the last rectangle wont be removed.

Comment: Thanks!  I am ashamed to admit I hadn't even considered this.

Answer (score 8):

You're removing items as you move forward with the index, causing you to not consider certain items for removal.

You should solve this by using an `Iterator` instead:

```
Iterator<?> it = yard.getChildren().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if(it.next() instanceof Rectangle) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

If you're using Java 8 you can do this instead which is more readable:

```
yard.getChildren().removeIf(Rectangle.class::isInstance);
```

Comment: Also `yard.getChildren().removeIf(Rectangle.class::isInstance);`.

Comment: Yeah, that's even better.

Comment: Thanks for the substitute, you've given me more to look into.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are removing items from your list in a loop.
If you need to remove items in a loop you should be using an iterator see:
[Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

When you remove item from collection then number of items in collection decreases too. So, you have to anticipate it and decrease working index to reflect such change:

```
public Pane yard = new Pane();
...
for(int i = 0; i < yard.getChildren().size(); i++)
{
    if(yard.getChildren().get(i) instanceof Rectangle)
    {
        yard.getChildren().remove(i--);// i-- is the change
    }
 }
```