# java iterator concurrent modification even with precautions

Tags: java, concurrency, iterator

I need to delete elements recursively from a list, but even with an iterator applied to a copy of the subject, I get concurrent modification error.

```
List<Referee> referees=videogame.getGamers();
Iterator<Referee> iter= referees.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()){
    Referee ref= iter.next();
    if(ref.getTheGameIsOver())
    videogame.removeReferee(ref);
}
```

Comment: What does `removeReferee` do? Does it remove from the same `List` that `getGamers` returns and is iterated on by `iter`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java)

Comment: Or when using Java 8: `videogame.getGamers().removeIf(Referee::getTheGameIsOver);`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying the underlying collection while the `Iterator` is iterating over it.  That is what is causing the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Instead, call [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) on the `Iterator` itself.  It removes the most recently iterated item with causing this exception.  Replace

```
videogame.removeReferee(ref);
```

with

```
iter.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way of using it will be as follows and it makes sense because the iterator object knows where it is in the list as the list is being navigated.

```
List<Referee> referees=videogame.getGamers();
Iterator<Referee> iter= referees.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()){
    Referee ref= iter.next();
    if(ref.getTheGameIsOver())
    iter.remove()
}
```

Please refer  http://durgaprasadtechie.blogspot.com/2011/07/concurrentmodificationexception-fail.html