# Getting UnsupportedOperationException when i remove elements at particular index in List<List<String>>?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, arraylist, unsupportedoperation

I am having `List<List<String>>` data this way,

```
List<List<String>> repdata = [
    ["1185","R","4t","G","06","L","GT","04309","2546","2015","CF FE","01H1","20","23840","FF20"],
    ["1192","R","11t","H","06","L","SA","04772","8345","2015","BZ C8 FE","01D6","13","33390","LC13"]]
```

I want to remove particularly, values at index 14 in the innerlists.

ex: in this inner list data

```
[["1185","R","4t","G","06","L","GT","04309","2546","2015","CF FE","01H1","20","23840","FF20"]]
```

I want to remove FF20,

And this has to be repeated for all the inner lists in the `List<List<String>> repdata`.

So, my final `List<List<String>>` would be this way,

```
List<List<String>> repdata = [
["1185","R","4t","G","06","L","GT","04309","2546","2015","CF FE","01H1","FF20","23840"],
["1192","R","11t","H","06","L","SA","04772","8345","2015","BZ C8 FE","01D6","13","33390"]
```

Actually this `List<List<String>> repdata is = criteria.list()` from hibernate. which is Transformed this way,

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.TO_LIST);
```

I tired removing this way,

```
List<List<String>> repdata = cr.list();
        for( List<String> list: repdata ){
            if( list.size() > 14){                              
                list.remove(14);
            }           
        }
```

But i am continuously getting `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that `cr.list()` returns a fixed size list which cannot be modified?

Comment: I suspect `Criteria#list` returns an unmodifiable `List`, such as obtained by `Collections#unmodifiableList`.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents) for instructions on how to create a deep copy of your `List`.

Comment: For loop and removal are a bad combination. Please use iterator or sth else mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java

Comment: What does `repdata.getClass()` print? and so as the `list.getClass()` . That should give you a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I dont have enough information available, I suspect that the list returned is probably fixed size (or unmodifiable in some other way). One example is the list we get from `Arrays.asList` to which cannot add/remove anything.We can't structurally modify this List.

The solution may be to initialize a list implementation using the items in current list. A LinkedList supports faster remove and may be suitable. Something like:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(your_list));
```

You can also use `ArrayList` if it suits your requirement.

Comment: yes ofcourse, I was able to only edit it.. Is there is any other way to remove it? –

Comment: In that case you need to copy the element to a new ArrayList (or any other implementation) and then you can remove.

Answer (score 0):

We shouldn't use the remove method of a List. Instead, traversing it using the iterator and using the iterator's own remove method is useful. Because when using list's remove method, ConcurrentModificationException will be thrown.