# Why is using the for-each loop on an ArrayList not working?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I've [stumbled upon this code](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/05/top-10-mistakes-java-developers-make/), which throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d"));

for (String s : list) {
    if (s.equals("a"))
        list.remove(s);
}
```

If you add an Iterator and use a while-loop, the code works fine:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d"));
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String s = iter.next();

    if (s.equals("a")) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

I dont understand, why it is necessary, to use `Iterator<String>` in this case. 
Is it because of the ArrayList not having some sort of ability to get iterated, altough it is a [subclass of Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)?

Is it necessary to use the while-loop, or could you produce a version with a for-loop?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java

Comment: From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html : Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) is modified while iterating over it, in most of the implementations, a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) is thrown.

The "foreach" version:

```
for (String s : list) {
    if (s.equals("a"))
        list.remove(s);
}
```

internally is equivalent to

```
for(Iterator<String> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    String s = i.next();
    if (s.equals("a"))
        list.remove(s);
}
```

As you can see, an interator is created, but the list is modified directly. The `list` can only be modified by the iterator `i` used to iterate over it.

Comment: you are missing a call to `next` :)

Comment: You're right, thanks!

Comment: By `modifying` do you mean only remove or would adding elements have the same problem?

Comment: @hamena314 Not necessarily a Problem when adding, but you cannot be sure. Implementations may vary. So using the iterator to modify is the only guaranteed safe way.

Answer (score 7):

Your link actually explains it pretty well:

> In the foreach loop, compiler will make the .next() called after the operation of removing element, which caused the ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 3):

The `for` uses an iterator internally. But you delete on the list directly => CME. The internal call to `next` after the deletion will throw it because it finds the list modified.

In the example with `while`, you delete through the iterator, which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When removing object from collections, use ***ITERATORS***

Your code does not work because you are modifying the collection while looping over it. According to Oracle's *javadoc* the only safe way to do it is **using iterators**.

> Note that *Iterator.remove()* is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.

Have a look at [this for further infos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html)