# Remove data from list while iterating kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to kotlin programming. What I want is that I want to remove a particular data from a list while iterating through it, but when I am doing that my app is crashing.

```
for ((pos, i) in listTotal!!.withIndex()) {

            if (pos != 0 && pos != listTotal!!.size - 1) {

                if (paymentsAndTagsModel.tagName == i.header) {
                    //listTotal!!.removeAt(pos)
                    listTotal!!.remove(i)
                }



            }
        }
```

OR

```
 for ((pos,i) in listTotal!!.listIterator().withIndex()){
            if (i.header == paymentsAndTagsModel.tagName){
                listTotal!!.listIterator(pos).remove()
            }

        }
```

The exception which I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's forbidden to [modify a collection through its interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java) while iterating over it. The only way to mutate the collection contents is to use `Iterator.remove`.

However using `Iterator`s can be unwieldy and in vast majority of cases it's better to treat the collections as immutable which Kotlin encourages. You can use a `filter` to  create a new collections like so:

```
listTotal = listTotal.filterIndexed { ix, element ->
    ix != 0 && ix != listTotal.lastIndex && element.header == paymentsAndTagsModel.tagName
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, Sir I used your solution but the thing is I have to notify my adapter for data change but it's not working

Comment: @AnujMody Please provide more details about what adapter you are using. Have you called [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())  ?

Comment: There is a much better answer from @murgupluoglu now.

Answer (score 45):

```
val numbers = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val numberIterator = numbers.iterator()
while (numberIterator.hasNext()) {
    val integer = numberIterator.next()
    if (integer < 3) {
        numberIterator.remove()
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the Kotlin docs clearly state the following: "For iterating mutable collections, there is MutableIterator that extends Iterator with the element removal function remove(). So, you can remove elements from a collection while iterating it."

Answer (score 37):

use removeAll

```
pushList?.removeAll {  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(
      System.currentTimeMillis() - it.date) > THRESHOLD }
```

Comment: If you check the code, this is a *very* effective and quick way to filter a MutableList in-place! `.retainAll()` is very similar, but the predicate is negated.

Comment: What's the difference between `removeAll` and `removeIf` ? It seems both do the same thing, no?

Comment: @androiddeveloper `removeAll` is in `kotlin.collections.MutableCollections` and `removeIf` is in `java.util.Collections`

Comment: @Archmede But do they do the same thing?

Comment: @androiddeveloper the javadocs have very similar descriptions

Comment: @Archmede So are they doing the same thing?

Comment: This removes the elements, but not while iterating through the list.

Answer (score 23):

The answer by miensol seems perfect.

However, I don't understand the context for using the `withIndex` function or `filteredIndex`. You can use the `filter` function just by itself.

> You don't need access to the index the list is at, if you're using
>   lists.

Also, I'd strongly recommend working with a data class if you already aren't. Your code would look something like this

Data Class

```
data class Event(
        var eventCode : String,
        var header : String
)
```

Filtering Logic

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){

    val eventList : MutableList<Event> = mutableListOf(
            Event(eventCode = "123",header = "One"),
            Event(eventCode = "456",header = "Two"),
            Event(eventCode = "789",header = "Three")
    )


    val filteredList = eventList.filter { !it.header.equals("Two") }

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot!    
list = list.filter { !(it.ID== ID) }.toMutableList()

Answer (score 9):

The following code works for me:

```
val iterator = listTotal.iterator()
for(i in iterator){
    if(i.haer== paymentsAndTagsModel.tagName){
        iterator.remove()
    }
}
```

You can also read [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/iterator.html) article.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you can use:

```
yourMutableCollection.removeIf { someLogic == true }
```

However, I'm working with an Android app that must support APIs older than 24.
In this case removeIf can't be used.

Here's a solution that is nearly identical to that implemented in Kotlin Collections that doesn't rely on Predicate.test - which is why API 24+ is required in the first place

```
 //This function is in Kotlin Collections but only for Android API 24+
fun <E> MutableCollection<E>.removeIff(filter: (E) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    var removed = false
    val iterator: MutableIterator<E> = this.iterator()
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        val value = iterator.next()
        if (filter.invoke(value)) {
            iterator.remove()
            removed = true
        }
    }
    return removed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

People didn't break iteration in previous posts dont know why. It can be simple but also with extensions and also for Map:

```
fun <T> MutableCollection<T>.removeFirst(filter: (T) -> Boolean) =
    iterator().removeIf(filter)

fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, V>.removeFirst(filter: (K, V) -> Boolean) =
    iterator().removeIf { filter(it.key, it.value) }

fun <T> MutableIterator<T>.removeFirst(filter: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    for (item in this) if (filter.invoke(item)) {
        remove()
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop, here is the kotlin extension function:

```
fun <E> MutableList<E>.removeIfMatch(isMatchConsumer: (existingItem: E) -> Boolean) {
    var index = 0
    var lastIndex = this.size -1

    while(index <= lastIndex && lastIndex >= 0){
        when {
            isMatchConsumer.invoke(this[index]) -> {
                this.removeAt(index)
                lastIndex-- // max is decreased by 1
            }
            else -> index++ // only increment if we do not remove
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find `removeIfMatch`. Instead I see 2 functions that seem like they do the same thing: `removeAll` and `removeIf` . How come?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Make sure you're using a `MutableList` and not a `List`

Comment: @Archmede Hm it's of ArrayList. Important?

Comment: @androiddeveloper `ArrayList` implements `MutableList` so it doesn't matter

Comment: @Archmede So it's the same?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that will suit small collections. For example set of listeners in some controller.

```kotlin
inline fun <T> MutableCollection<T>.forEachSafe(action: (T) -> Unit) {
    val listCopy = ArrayList<T>(this)
    for (element: T in listCopy) {
        if (this.contains(element)) {
            action(element)
        }
    }
}
```

It makes sure that elements of collection can be removed safely even from outside code.