# Removing elements with multiple arguments of an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to remove an instance of an ArrayList, but with the code I have now it lists the movies removed. I have an ArrayList that takes `title`, `year`, `genre` and `balance`. The goal is to remove from the list using only title and year.

I have tried a for-each loop, but that leads to `ConcurrentModificationException` error, and I am not sure how use use Iterators to make it work for this example.

It is supposed to remove the instance specified by title and year so that when it lists the moviesAvailable, the list would be updated. However when listing it shows all movies (probably because it is not actually removing the movie).

Comment: If you do not override `equals` on your Movie class how can anything tell that one instance equals another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java, or use index in for-loop to remove the item. You should not use for-each to remove elements see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html

Comment: How would I go about using an iterator in this case?

Answer (score 1):

One way to remove the targeted movie is via the `Collections.removeIf()` method:

```
public void removeMovie() {
    System.out.println("\nRemoving a movie.");
    System.out.print("Enter the title of the movie: ");
    String title = In.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
    int year = In.nextInt();
    moviesAvailable.removeIf(movie -> movie.hasType(title, year));
    // other stuff...
}
```

## Note

- The `removeIf` method iterates through your collection and true to its name, removes an element (a movie in this case) which satisfy the condition.
- If your entry was not deleted, please check to see if `title` and `year` are correct. For example, does `title` contain a trailing new line?

Comment: I tried that, but when when it lists the movies whichever one I delete still shows up

Comment: Please check to see if your `title` and `year` are correct.

Comment: I checked this solution. It seems to work. I have used scanner to input movie and year, and the matching happens in a case sensitive manner.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
 moviesAvailable.removeIf(m -> m.hasType("s",2));
```