# Iterating over a map of labels and disposing them

Tags: java, dictionary, swt

I wrote the following code:

```
final Iterator<Entry<Label, Label>> it = dataLabels.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    final Map.Entry<Label, Label> pairs = it.next();
    dataLabels.remove(pairs.getKey());
    pairs.getValue().dispose();
    pairs.getKey().dispose();
}
```

It iterates over a map of labels (type: `Map<Label, Label>`) and dispose of each one of them (after removing it from the map).

I feel like this code does not do what I expect. I think that it stops iterating after the first loop (tried to add printed message to see the behavior).

Does the code do what I expect (disposing of all the labels)? If not, how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try running your code? It should throw a ConcurrentModificationException, since you can`t change the map while you are iterating over it.

Comment: Use the iterator to remove it from the map, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `remove` on a map while you are iterating through the entries.

You can either use the iterator `remove` method as shown in the other answer or just clear the map at the end:

```
for (Map.Entry<Label, Label> dataLabel : dataLabels.entrySet()) {
  dataLabel.getKey().dispose();
  dataLabel.getValue().dispose();
}
dataLabels.clear();
```

or using streams:

```
dataLabels.forEach((key, value) -> { key.dispose(); value.dispose(); });
dataLabels.clear();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove one by one try this,

```
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Label,Label>> i = dataLabels.entrySet().iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry<String,String> entry = i.next();
       // Do something
       i.remove();
    }
```

or else you can clear entire map using `dataLabels.clear()`

By using `dataLabels.clear()` you can reuse the `dataLabels` map.

If you don't need to reuse it set it to `null`

```
dataLabels = null;
```

Comment: We`ll he could just use clear() on the map, after he is done disposing in that case. No need for a second iteration.