# remove element from ArrayList inside for(Particle p: particles) loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, processing

I know how to remove an element using the remove() function inside a for loop this way :

```
 // ArrayList<Particle> particles;

    for(int = 0; i < particles.size(); i++){
     if(condition){
     particles.remove(i)
     }    
    }
```

but I'd like to know how to do the same thing using this alternative for loop syntax that I find more elegant :

```
// ArrayList<Particle> particles;

for(Particle p:particles){
 if(condition){
// remove particle
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java)

Comment: `particles = new ArrayList<>();` or `particles.clear();`

Comment: There’s always `particles.removeIf(p -> condition)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that because you'll get a ConcurrentModificationException. ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when something you're iterating over is modified.

You need to create an iterator and use that to remove your elements. Here's an example:

```
Iterator iterator = particles.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.remove();
    iterator.next();
}
```

Comment: This will remove every element, though.  The OP's first example only removes every other element.

Comment: @azurefrog How so? He increments the iterator integer by one every time

Comment: Lists are not like arrays.  When you remove element 0, the rest are "re-indexed" down, so removing 0, then 1, then 2 removes what originally were the 0th, 2nd and 4th elements.

Comment: @azurefrog Oh I see. I overlooked that.

Comment: Well, to be fair, it's possible that the OP did, too... ;-)

Comment: @azurefrog I edited my answer to correspond with what OP's code would have done, but I guess the question is, is it OP's intent to remove every other element?

Comment: it seems though that I loose my class functions when I do so because I'm looping through an iterator and not an object anymore

Comment: @Asymetr well you could get the object of the type of your class from the return value of iterator.next()

Comment: and yes I did completely overlook that, I'm sorry, let me update

Comment: @Asymetr so what is your intention here? if you're just trying to remove all the elements from the ArrayList, there are easier ways to accomplish that.

Comment: I'm almost good I'm just trying to figure out how to get my object back using Particle particle = iterator.next();

Answer (score -2):

Use the Iterator class :

```
Iterator iterator = particles.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.remove();
    iterator.next();
}
```

Comment: this all works except I get a type mismatch "java.lang.Object" does not match with "Particle" when I try to 
Particle particle = iterator.next();
do you know how I could resolve this ? Isn't next() suppose to iterate through my array of objects ?